# Stream support in Midori browser at Raspberry

Tags: html, video-streaming, midori

I have video grabber USB stick and streaming via ustreamer on port 8409 in MJPG format. I need show stream locally in browser javascript application in IMG tag. It works pretty well in Chromium. But Chromium takes plenty of resources so I would rather use more lightweight **Midori 7.0** browser. Javascript application works well but Midori does not show **stream in IMG tag** correctly. Seems displays picture for a while and remaining time content is blank in period of 20 secs or so. I cannot see stream in *Inspect* as well.

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="http://localhost:8409/stream" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I open URL `http://localhost:8409/stream` directly (in Midori) then I can see stream correctly. *Inspect* command is not possible in this case.

Can I somehow persuade IMG tag to display streaming content or is it not supported in Midori so I must stick on Chromium ?